# Yii2 type cast column as integer

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

In Yii2, I have a model, for example `Product`. What I want to do is select an extra column from the database as int

This is an example of what I'm doing:

```
Product::find()->select(['id', new Expression('20 as type')])
            ->where(['client' => $clientId])
            ->andWhere(['<>', 'hidden', 0]);
```

The problem is, I'm getting the result as "20". In other words, 20 is returned as string. How can I make sure that the selected is Integer?

I tried the following also but its not working:

```
    Product::find()->select(['id', new Expression('CAST(20 AS UNSIGNED) as type')])
            ->where(['client' => $clientId])
            ->andWhere(['<>', 'hidden', 0]);
```

Comment: do you have a raw `SQL` query that is currently working if you run in the `console` or `phpmyadmin`

Comment: Mmm, yes there is. Ill add it here as well

Comment: added an answer for you see if that helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can manually typecast in `Product`'s [`afterFind()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterFind()-detail) function or use [`AttributeTypecastBehavior`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-attributetypecastbehavior.html).

But above all, you'll have to define a custom `attribute` for alias you use in the query. For example `$selling_price` in your `Product` model if you use `selling _price` as an alias.

```
public $selling_price;
```

After that, you can use any of the following approaches.

**1)** [`afterFind`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterFind()-detail)

Example Below

```
public function afterFind() {
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->selling_price = (int) $this->selling_price;
}
```

**2)** [`AttributeTypecastBehavior`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-attributetypecastbehavior.html)

Example below

```
 public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'typecast' => [
                'class' => \yii\behaviors\AttributeTypecastBehavior::className(),
                'attributeTypes' => [
                    'selling_price' => \yii\behaviors\AttributeTypecastBehavior::TYPE_INTEGER,

                ],
                'typecastAfterValidate' => false,
                'typecastBeforeSave' => false,
                'typecastAfterFind' => true,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I opted for the second answer, and it works perfectly. Thank you v. much! :)

Comment: very nice answer +1 for defining multiple approaches to the same question